# Not updating, but the promise return success

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The update is not working, but the promise is returning success. I think it may be with the Where in the sequelize query not finding the value from the array of objects productsCodeArr.

```
const orderid = req.params.orderid
const productsCodeArr = convertedInputs.map(code => {
                    return ({
                        id: code.id,
                        picked: code.picked,
                        notPicked: code.notPicked
                    });
                })
                
                
if(productsCodeArr) {
                
db.Detallepedido.update({
                    pickeado: productsCodeArr.picked,
                    nopickeado: productsCodeArr.notPicked
                },
                {
                    where: {
                        pedido_id: orderid,
                        producto_id: productsCodeArr.id
                    }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Success!');
                }})
            .catch(reason => {
                console.log(reason);
            })
```

Comment: An array doesn't have properties like `picked` or `id`....the individual objects inside the array do. You need an update for each item in the array or a bulkUpdate method if it exists for whatever db you are using

Comment: i'm using mysql. I was considering this: bulkCreate([...], { updateOnDuplicate: ["id"] })

Comment: I have not used sequalize for a very very long time. Check docs for a bulk update method or you will need to do individual updates in loop

Comment: I'll use a foreach and test it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did it!
I used Promise.all with a map of the array.

```
Promise.all(productsCodeArr.map(object=>{
                return db.Detallepedido.update({
                    pickeado: object.picked,
                    nopickeado: object.notPicked
                },
                {
                    where: {
                        pedido_id: orderid,
                        producto_id: object.id
                    }
                })}))
```